# Open link new window and close current window not working in Safari only

Tags: javascript, safari

I've used the following example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681178/html-javascript-to-open-new-window-and-close-current-window):

```
function whenClicked() 
{
    window.close();
    opener.location.href = "http://www.somesite.com";

}
```

but amended to this:

```
function openLink()
{
    window.close();
    opener.location.href = this.href;
}
```

to open a link from a popup window. This works fine in IE, FF, Chrome & Opera but Safari doesn't want to play ball. Firstly, my popup window doesn't work, it opens in a new tab (but that's another issue) and when I click the link, the tab closes but the new link doesn't open.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Added an [if statement](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F5899783%2Fdetect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-opera-with-user-agent&ei=oboGVa-gD63d7QaJlYG4DQ&usg=AFQjCNGwz8kHynIdutkaJ0ck3ADgXDohmA&sig2=kETgmw49L653PdRWXql1Iw&bvm=bv.88198703,d.d2s) to detect Safari and deal with it for now but a solution would be ace!

```
function openLink()
{
    if (isSafari = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/)) {
            opener.open(this.href);
        }
    else {
        window.close();
        opener.open(this.href);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally you should post your solution as an answer rather than editing the question if you have enough reputation.