# jQuery not closing window

Tags: jquery, window

I'm making a form for an e-commerce site for the user to request a PDF about an item.
The form works fine and sends the user to the "Thanks" page.
On the thanks page I have jQuery set an interval to close the window after 5 seconds.
But it does not work, neither does embedding the close command in a link.
However, the interval will work if the "Thanks" page opens in a new tab.

Here is the code in the php file (gets called after form has been successfully submitted).

```
/* Results rendered as HTML */

    $theResults = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Thanks</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/00000001/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //wait a few seconds and close the window
    setInterval(function()
    {
        window.close();
    }, 5000);
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    border: none;
}

#general-copy{
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: -5px auto auto 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    font-weight:100;
    text-align: justify;
    z-index: 3;
}

</style>
</head>
<body><br /><br />
<div class="lettertext">
Thank you for your request.<br />
We will email you a pdf all about $item2Field.
<br><br>
<p style="font-size: 10px;">This window should close itself in 5 seconds.<br>
If it doesn't please click <a href="javascript:window.close()">here</a> to return to the site.
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo "$theResults"; 


?>
```

If you wish to see this running live you can try it out [here](http://ecofirstart.com/mm5/request-info.html).

Comment: Really, you should avoid the need for new windows and closing them, it is prevented frequently.  If you need a pop-up, create an overlay.

Comment: Pretty much what @Orbling said, your scenario looks more like a bad use of jQuery.

Comment: I will probably transfer it in as an overlay later, but for now a pop-up is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

[window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close) @ MDN (Mozilla docs)

> This method is only allowed to be
>   called for windows that were opened by
>   a script using the window.open method.
>   If the window was not opened by a
>   script, the following error appears in
>   the JavaScript Console: Scripts may
>   not close windows that were not opened
>   by script.

W3C [norm on HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-window-close) agrees :

> The close() method on Window objects
>   should, if the corresponding browsing
>   context A is an auxiliary browsing
>   context that was created by a script
>   (as opposed to by an action of the
>   user), and if the browsing context of
>   the script that invokes the method is
>   allowed to navigate the browsing
>   context A, close the browsing context
>   A (and may discard it too).

Comment: Aha! So, since this is a pop-up form anyways I would need to trigger the window opening in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try getting reference to your window. if you used window.open(), try this:

```
var wind = window.open(params);// then close..
wind.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in Google Chrome and is working.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //wait a few seconds and close the window
    setInterval(function()
    {
        window.close();
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

I have read that in IE also works. However, maybe you're using FireFox to test your page, and that's why is not working. Probably you can [search for](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=132486) a solution targeting FireFox.

**UPDATE**: I have tested another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760422/how-can-i-close-a-window-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-3) which works. However, it needs higher privileges:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
function closeWindow() {
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
    alert("This will close the window");
    window.open('','_self');
    window.close();
}
    //wait a few seconds and close the window
    setInterval(function()
    {
        window.close();
        closeWindow();
    }, 5000);
});
```

The result is an alert message asking the user about the level of privileges. Probably is not the best way to go. Maybe, instead of closing a window, you can redirect the user to something relevant.