# how to close web browser when clicking a button in firefox?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I close a window with Javascript on Mozilla Firefox 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760422/how-can-i-close-a-window-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-3)

i used the code window.close();

it works well for Internet Explorer but it not worked in firefox

Comment: This is what the `X` in the top right corner of the browser application is for.

Answer (score 0):

check in "about:config" the value of "dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows"
anyway, did you tried with
`self.close();`

Comment: ya i tried its also not worked

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.close()
```

can only be used on windows you created with

```
  window.open()
```

**or** the Current window, in most common browsers that respect the scope of JavaScript in a user-friendly way. When this method it calls it checks the

```
  window.opener
```

The access to other windows is prohibited due to security reasons. (other websites could close your windows without telling ;)

IE goes a bit out of that bounds with some (tiny-small) lack of taking care of the security side effects (IE. risks)

**[more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.close)**