# close current web form in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How i can close current web form in web based application?
I have tried with following code:

```
mybutton.Attributes.Add("onclick","window.close()")
```

But its not working
Help me. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "close current web form"? You want to close a browser window? or send the user to a different page?

Comment: I have to close current window in my web based application

Comment: are you getting any javascript error, as I have tested the same and its working on my side

Comment: I am not getting any error, but window getting still open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following script to close the current window in Chrome and IE (I checked in IE8).

```
mybutton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('', '_self');window.close();");
```

but it still won't work in Firefox. See more info on this: [How can I close a window with Javascript on Mozilla Firefox 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760422/how-can-i-close-a-window-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-3)

But because it is a workaround (as Kangkan said `window.close()` should be used only to close popup window created by `window.open()` ), it is not a reliable solution and can be broken if a new browser version is out.

Bottom line: there is no reliable, universal solution for your problem, there is no proper way to close a non-popup window from javascript. If you can rely on the fact that your site will be used only in IE, Chrome, etc. you can use a workaround/hack (see above - but don't forget, it can easily be broken in next browser release), otherwise you should consider a different approach of the problem, instead of closing the window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.close()` to close a pop-up window only. If you really need to close the window, use a pop-up instead. However review why the closing is important? You may consider a redirection (either server.transfer or response.redirect).

Update:

Looking at the discussion at this stage, we need to see the relevance of why wee need to close the window as desired. What is the business value that we are achieving?