# Close the window in firefox

Tags: javascript

I want to close window. my script is working fine in ie and firefox 2.x but not working in firefox 3.x and above . i am using the following script.

```
function closeWindow() {
    window.open('', '_self', ''); //bug fix
    window.close();    
}
```

Please find some solution. 
thanks to all.

Comment: Please see the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760422/how-can-i-close-a-window-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-3). Short answer: you cannot close a window that has not been created by javascript in a patched FireFox 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
function closeWindow() {
            if (navigator.appName != "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
                netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
            }
            alert("This will close the window");
            window.open('', '_self');
            window.close();
        }
```

This is working on both firefox and ie

Comment: No longer working in Firefox 8, but it does fix the warning message when using IE 8

Answer (score 0):

window.open() returns a reference to the opened window, and you can use that for close().  For example:

```
var win = window.open(url)
win.close()
```

Firefox (correctly) won't let you close a window you didn't open.