# how do i close firefox browsers window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
  function CloseWindow()
  {
        window.close();
  }
```

The above code is working fine for IE but Firefox does not allows to close browsers window
any solution???

Comment: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/11/javascript-windowclose-does-not-work-in.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I close a window with Javascript on Mozilla Firefox 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760422/how-can-i-close-a-window-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similar post answer

```
function closeWindow() {
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
    alert("This will close the window");
    window.open('','_self');
    window.close();
}

closeWindow();
```

reason
For security reasons, your script cannot close a window/tab that it did not open.

The solution is to present the age prompt at an earlier point in the navigation history. Then, you can choose to allow them to enter your site or not based on their input.

Instead of closing the page that presents the prompt, you can simply say, "Sorry", or perhaps redirect the user to their homepage.

Comment: How do you know this is related to an prompt? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use self object

```
<a href="javascript:self.close()">Close Window</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1** : Type the in address bar as " about:config " and press enter key

**Step 2**:  "i'll be careful , I promise"   Click on this button

**Step 3**: " dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows;true "   Search this line and Double click on it.

Comment: Not sure how you accomodate your users who will have to follow the same instructions.