# How to close a window using GWT or Ext-GWT (GXT)?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I wanna close the browser window (similar to javascript:window.close()). Is there any
correpsponding API in GWT or in Ext-GWT (GXT)?

I don't want to make a native call to do this, I want a Java solution.

> native public static void close()/*-{
>       $wnd.close(); }-*/;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the native call? Java code will be compiled into JavaScript anyway.

Comment: I'm just using Ext-GWT to don't use JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT provides access to browser window's methods via the class `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window` with some static methods. Currently there is no `close()` method (unlike `open()`).
Since the GWT Window class itself is working with the JSNI I don't think you will find a possibility to access the browser window in a pure Java way (and how should that work at all?).
If you don't want to use JSNI in your existing code you could create something like the GWT Window class adjusted to your needs.

Comment: You are right, there is no way to don't use a JSNI solution, but in FF it doesn't work without change a variable in browser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760422/how-can-i-close-a-window-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-3

Comment: @elloalisboa: Thanks for the hint. That's good to know... Until know, I never needed this function in production.