# Tridion CMS custom page - Window.close not working in FF

Tags: tridion

we created a custom page which trigered by the component as Custom URL,

we have a close button on the page which calles a js function of window.close ,

it works for I.e and Chrome but not in FF.

we tried also to use local var that receive the window.open("","_self") and close it but didn't succeeded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I close a window with Javascript on Mozilla Firefox 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760422/how-can-i-close-a-window-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-3)

Answer (score 3):

This is a browser issue and isn't specific to Tridion.  Have a look at this thread which answers a similar question: [How can I close a window with Javascript on Mozilla Firefox 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760422/how-can-i-close-a-window-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-3)