# window.close() is not working in FF

Tags: javascript, firefox

We are using `window.close()` to close the current browser tab. It works for IE, Chrome, Safari, but not for FF.

We tried lot of solutions provided on Internet, but it seems they are not working.

```
window.open('','_parent','');
window.close();
```

Comment: Does that really work in other browsers? You can't normally close windows you didn't open yourself. It's been that way since the late 1990s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually due to security reason and user experience aspects you can
>   now can't cause the browser to be closed[Completely], only popup
>   windows can be closed or the one parent to a script.

check the following [mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/966137)

possible duplicate of [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760422/how-can-i-close-a-window-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-3)